# Updating account info into database not working, PHP error: "Call to a member function"

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am developing an app that uses login with SharedPreferences. The next step is to add an activity that updates the database, if the user wants to update his info from within the app. I have wrote the code, but when  I run it, there seems to be a problem with JSON. I have checked using breakpoints, and the values are allright, but the "s=" section says  `Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\Users\wamp64\www\App.php on line <i>189</i>` So, I went in my php and checked the line 189, but I did not see anything wrong. I used the exact syntax for login/registration and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Firstly, I will add the line 189 from .php:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon);
```

UpdateInfo.java

```
class ActualizareUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("nume", Nume);
            params.put("email", Email);
            params.put("prenume", Prenume);
            params.put("telefon", Telefon);
            params.put("id", id);

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_UPDATE_USER, params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //hiding the progressbar after completion
            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject objs = new JSONObject(s);

                //if no error in response
                if (!objs.getBoolean("error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objs.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //getting the user from the response
                    JSONObject userJson = objs.getJSONObject("user");

                    //creating a new user object
                    User user = new User(
                            userJson.getString("Nume"),
                            userJson.getString("Prenume"),
                            userJson.getString("Adresa_mail"),
                            userJson.getString("Numar_telefon"),
                            userJson.getString("Parola"),
                            userJson.getInt("ID_UTILIZ")
                    );

                    //storing the user in shared preferences
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profil.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A aparut o eroare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

App.php , update part:

```
case 'updateuser':


if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('nume','email','prenume', 'telefon', 'id'))){
                    $prenume = $_POST["prenume"];
                    $nume =$_POST["nume"];
                    $email =$_POST["email"];
                    $telefon =$_POST["telefon"];
                    $id =$_POST["id"];

                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILIZ FROM informatii_persoane WHERE ID_UTILIZ = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                if($stmt->num_rows < 1){
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Nu se poate identifica un cont';
                    $stmt->close();
                }else{
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE INTO informatii_persoane (Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon);

                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILIZ, Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon, Parola FROM informatii_persoane WHERE Adresa_mail = ?"); 
                        $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($id, $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon, $parola);
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        $user = array(
                            'Nume'=>$nume, 
                            'Prenume'=>$prenume,
                            'Adresa_mail'=>$email,
                            'Numar_telefon'=>$telefon,
                            'Parola'=>$parola,
                            'ID_UTILIZ'=>$id
                        );

                        $stmt->close();

                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Date actualizate cu success'; 
                        $response['user'] = $user; 
                    }
                }

            }else{
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'A aparut o eroare'; 
            }

        break;
```

Updated .php:

```
case 'updateuser':
            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('nume','email','prenume', 'telefon', 'id'))){
                $prenume = $_POST["prenume"];
                $nume =$_POST["nume"];
                $email =$_POST["email"];
                $telefon =$_POST["telefon"];
                $id =$_POST["id"];

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILIZ FROM informatii_persoane WHERE ID_UTILIZ = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
                $stmt->close();

                if($rows < 1){
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Nu se poate identifica un cont';

                }else{
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE INTO informatii_persoane (Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon);

                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILIZ, Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon, Parola FROM informatii_persoane WHERE Adresa_mail = ?"); 
                        $stmt1->bind_param("s",$email);
                        $stmt1->execute();
                        $stmt1->bind_result($id, $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon, $parola);
                        $stmt1->fetch();
                        $stmt1->close();
                        $user = array(
                            'Nume'=>$nume, 
                            'Prenume'=>$prenume,
                            'Adresa_mail'=>$email,
                            'Numar_telefon'=>$telefon,
                            'Parola'=>$parola,
                            'ID_UTILIZ'=>$id
                        );


                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Date actualizate cu success'; 
                        $response['user'] = $user; 
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }

            }else{
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'A aparut o eroare'; 
            }

        break;
```

informatii_persoane structure:

```
   create table if not exists informatii_persoane (
ID_utiliz int auto_increment primary key,
Nume varchar(50),
Prenume varchar(50),
Adresa_mail varchar (50) unique ,
Numar_telefon text ,
Notificare_SMS enum('Da','Nu'),
Notificari_aplicatie enum('Da','Nu'),
Parola varchar(50),
nr_alerte_semnalizate int,
nr_alerte_corecte int,
nr_alerte_partial_corecte int,
nr_lerte_incorecte int,   -- vezi aici cum faci %
scor float   -- il facem din cele doua de mai sus
);
```

Comment: The error tells you that your $stmt variable is of type boolean, but you are trying to access it as if it were an object.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysqli_error.php before the bind_param line?

Comment: @Costin, share the structure of informatii_persoane Table

Comment: @AmanjotKaur I have tried to add `$stmt-> error; ` before bind_param but i get another error. I do not think I used it correctly. I update the question with Table's structure

Comment: @Costin Have you tried my latest updated answer.. the first 2 lines of my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Update informatii_persoane set Nume = ?, Prenume = ?, Adresa_mail = ?, Numar_telefon = ?  where ID_UTILIZ = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon, $id);
```

> The problem lies in  $stmt->close();

You have not closed the select statement and then starting the insert statement.
You can have multiple statements open at the same time. But you must close them eventually.

> Also, you have written the INSERT query wrong.

check it

```
UPDATE INTO informatii_persoane (Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

change to

```
INSERT INTO informatii_persoane (Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

/************************************************************/

> **Important Note**

Also, if you want to find out the error in the query,
    add `echo $conn->error;` below and above the line that gives an error

Comment: I have tried this solution but the same error it's still present

Comment: I have updated the code. The error is still with `$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon);` I will try to run the query in MySQL

Comment: The situation is the same, even when I switch to INSERT.

Comment: I have tried your code on my local machine.. It works fine. @Costin Data was inserted in DB

Answer (score 0):

**There is an issue with your query. The prepare() might return FALSE.**

Can you check with :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Note :**

If table name or column names are not correct means it will throw error

Comment: I have double checked the column names and table name, they are the same

Answer (score 0):

my advice to you would be trying to use an ORM, it simplifies such processes tremendously. I always use [redbean](https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php)  for your case you need need to configure the DB like this:

```
class ADXdbConfig
```

{

```
private $db;

private $host;

private $db_user;

private $pass_phrase;

public function __construct()
{
    if (! isset($this->host) || ! isset($this->db_user) || ! isset($this->db) || ! isset($this->pass_phrase)) {
        if (null !== getenv("OPTS_ENV") && "live" == getenv("OPTS_ENV")) {
            $url = parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
            if (isset($url) && isset($url["host"]) && isset($url["user"])) {
                $this->host = $url["host"];
                $this->db_user = $url["user"];
                $this->pass_phrase = $url["pass"];
                $this->db = substr($url["path"], 1);
            }
        } else if (null !== getenv("OPTS_ENV") && "local" == getenv("OPTS_ENV")) {
            $this->host = getenv("PGQL_HOST");
            $this->db_user = getenv("PGQL_DB_USER");
            $this->pass_phrase = getenv("PGQL_DB_PASS");
            $this->db = getenv("PGQL_DB_NAME");
        } else {
            error_log("ERROR(ADXdbConfig):Unable to determine the environment(live/local)");
            throw new Exception("Unable to determine the environment(live/local)");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This method connects to the database.
 */
public function connect()
{
    if (null !== $this->host && null !== $this->db && null !== $this->db_user && null !== $this->pass_phrase) {
        $isConnected = R::testConnection();
        if ($isConnected === FALSE) {
            R::setup("pgsql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db", $this->db_user, $this->pass_phrase);
            // to allow underscores in table creation
            R::ext('xdispense', function ($type) {
                return R::getRedBean()->dispense($type);
            });
        }
    } else {
        error_log("ERROR(MDBconnection:connect): Undefined DB settings---------------");
        throw new Exception("Error connecting to the database.");
    }
}
```

}

Env vars can be so useful when you have to deploy on different environments. 
Then you can connect to the DB like this:

```
 $dbConnection = new ADXdbConfig();
 $dbConnection->connect();
```

And after you can update like this:

```
 $userProfileBean = R::load($tableName, $userProfile->getId());
        $userProfileBean->first_name = $userProfile->getFirstName() ?? $userProfileBean->first_name;
        $userProfileBean->last_name = $userProfile->getLastName() ?? $userProfileBean->last_name;
        $userProfileBean->phone_number = $userProfile->getPhoneNumber() ?? $userProfileBean->phone_number;
        $userProfileBean->address = $userProfile->getAddress() ?? $userProfileBean->address;
        $userProfileBean->last_update_by = $userProfile->getLastUpdatedBy();
        $userProfileBean->last_update_on = date("Y-m-d h:d:s");
        $userProfileId = R::store($userProfileBean);
```

For further details you can check more on redbean documentation. I hope this helps you on problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Amanjot Kaut it's also the correct one. The error was solved by changing the update query from :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE INTO informatii_persoane (Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon);
```

to :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Update informatii_persoane set Nume = ?, Prenume = ?, Adresa_mail = ?, Numar_telefon = ?  where ID_UTILIZ = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon, $id);
```